# Issue with Formula for complicated text not working

Tags: google-sheets, formula

So the issue i have is on the sheet below Column G formula is the same as Column H, but it is not working, i believe it is because of the complicated text it is looking for, any help is appreciated

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEeulAtoiHS810VyafJCu07EyvN6xIHjdaQo46Wb5ys/edit#gid=0

Comment: OR if you have a better way of doing what i'm trying to do on the first tab then i'm all ears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is due to the fact that square brackets are used in your data. Those represent a character class in regex. I changed the formula you had so that it now replaces those brackets. Result can be seen in the duplicated sheet, starting in G2. The formula I used is

```
=INDEX(QUERY({regexreplace('All Report'!$B$1:$B, "\[|\]",),'All Report'!$C$1:$C},"select count(Col1) where (Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|",REGEXREPLACE($M$2:$M$4, "\[|\]",))&"') and Col2='"&$A2&"' label count(Col1) ''"))
```

An alternative formula could be

```
=COUNTA(FILTER('All Report'!$B:$B, match('All Report'!$B:$B, $M$2:$M$4, 0), 'All Report'!$C:$C = $A2 ))
```

or even

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER('All Report'!$C:$C, match('All Report'!$B:$B, $M$2:$M$4, 0))=$A2 )
```

See if that helps?

Comment: That seems to be working perfectly on the test sheet, getting no output on the real sheet, and i'm unsure why

Comment: I noticed a trailing whitespace in "Group - [Test], A ".  That may cause some issues...

Comment: You may also want to try the alternative formula I added in the above post.

Comment: The Sumproduct formula worked perfectly thank-you, if I wanted to do the same but count when C:C had a blank instead of a name, would I just replace the match function with CountBlank?

Comment: @KenG: If don't need the filter condition specified in the match function you can replace it with isblank(C:C). However, if you still need that condition you can add the isblank around the first parameter of the filter or wrap the isblank around the output of the filter. I believe both should work.

Comment: That's great thankyou for following up!

Comment: i'm actually more lost than i thought i would be on this, i tried to put it after the filter like Filter(IfBlank or replacing match with it, but no dice

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can have a closer look?

Comment: Sure thing the sheet link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEeulAtoiHS810VyafJCu07EyvN6xIHjdaQo46Wb5ys/edit#gid=387278863 I've added on copy of main the countblank for individual named columns, i'm just unsure about the grouped ones

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(ISBLANK('All Report'!$C:$C), ISNUMBER(match('All Report'!$B:$B, $M$2:$M$4, 0))) will return 5 which seems to be correct.